# How to ensure if the user shared the ttext to meesaging apps

Tags: android, sharing

Using this code I share some text to any messaging app

```
String shareBody = getString(R.string.someText);
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "share_using"),ShareSth);
```

now, How I can get the result if user has shared the text or not ?

I used the onActivityResult which resultCode is 0 which means user canceled but really it is shared

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
{
   //resultCode is 0 which means user canceled but really it is shared 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Using this code I share some text to any messaging app

`ACTION_SEND` does not support `startActivityForResult()`. No `ACTION_SEND` activities should be calling `setResult()` to return a result.

> How I can get the result if user has shared the text or not ?

You can't. What happens inside the app that the user chooses is up to the user and the developers of that other app, not you.